# I am getting a lot of zygote64 logs on my app start. What does it means?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

On the app start, at the beginning of Logcat logs, there are a lot of zygote64 logs and they are repeating several times.

I have just pasted a single chunk of 4 of them. The other 3 are the same or looks so.

What does it mean?

Is something wrong with the app code or configuration?

```
2019-10-19 22:07:37.078 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.mantas.timetrackv1.Activities.MainActivityV2.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivityV2.java:50)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7183)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6944)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.timetrackv1-IEcloZJcBJJyuDjun3qIGw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.user.timetrackv1-IEcloZJcBJJyuDjun3qIGw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.mantas.timetrackv1.Activities.MainActivityV2.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivityV2.java:50)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7183)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6944)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
2019-10-19 22:07:37.238 2795-2795/com.example.user.timetrackv1 I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```